# Can not execute the following query because of the '-' in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl, alter-table

```
ALTER TABLE hotel_availability CHANGE idhotel-availability  idhotel_availability INT;
```

Need to execute above query but it can not execute because of  "-" symbol?how can i fixed it?

err:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-availability  idhotel_availability INT' at line 1

Comment: use backticks -> `\`idhotel-availability\``

Comment: This is because the `-` sign is used for substract operations

Answer (score 0):

Character `'-'` is not allowed in unquoted qualifiers. As [explained in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html), permitted characters are *basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore*.

So you would need to quote this identifier, using backticks:

```
ALTER TABLE hotel_availability CHANGE `idhotel-availability` idhotel_availability INT;
```